# How to script Network Preferences using the CLI

Tags: terminal, network, script, system-settings, defaults

As the title implies for development I enable/disable Web proxies, however doing it through the UI is slow and cumbersome its also pretty inflexible.

I'm looking to control the following checked settings:

[image: Advanced Network Settings]

I tried using the following script to identify any changes but it did not work:

```bsh
defaults read > current-defaults.txt

# Do change in UI and then run the following:
defaults read > changed-defaults.txt

diff current-defaults.txt changed-defaults.txt
```

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198257/how-can-i-script-the-setup-of-preferences-in-mac-os-x) has information but is not as specific to solve solve my needs

Comment: Based on the screen shot: `networksetup -setwebproxy "Wi-Fi" localhost 8080` and `networksetup -setsecurewebproxy "Wi-Fi" localhost 8080` assuming **Secure Web Proxy (HTTPS)** is set the same.

Comment: Do the answers to ["how to you toggle on and off a web proxy in os x from the command line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029471/how-to-you-toggle-on-and-off-a-web-proxy-in-os-x-from-the-command-line) cover what you need? BTW, another method is to make two network locations, and switch between them from the Apple menu (when you have more than one location, it gets a submenu to switch between them).

Answer (score 3):

Try `networksetup` ...  From `man networksetup` .. NOTE must be an admin to run it.

> DESCRIPTION
> The networksetup command is used to configure network settings typically configured in
> the System Preferences application. The networksetup command requires at least admin
> privileges to change network settings. If the "Require an administrator password to
> access system-wide preferences" option is selected in System Preferences > Security &
> Privacy, then root privileges are required to change network settings.

You can make changes to many OSX network settings using similar tools to linux platforms, using networksetup ensures everything running is properly informed, settings are saved, and upon reboot those saved values are still usable (exactly as if you had used System Preferences) - see this answer to another networking questions that [talks about how that works](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/352686/409922).

> The basic reason is that macOS has two different levels of network configuration: the live state (which ifconfig en0 down changes) and the "configuration database" which corresponds to the settings created in the Network pane of System Preferences and/or the networksetup command.

In this particular case the `-setwebproxy` and `-setsecurewebproxy` options change the proxy settings for a particular network service - e.g. HT user3439894 - these set the proxy on the *Wi-Fi* network service.

```sh
networksetup -setwebproxy "Wi-Fi" localhost 8080
networksetup -setsecurewebproxy "Wi-Fi" localhost 8080
```

Depending on the actual network configuration will need to choose the appropriate service..

> -setwebproxy networkservice domain portnumber authenticated username
> password

> Set Web proxy for *networkservice* with *domain* and *port number*. Turns proxy on. Optionally, specify *on* or *off* for
> *authenticated* to enable and disable authenticated proxy support.
> Specify *username* and *password* if you turn authenticated proxy
> support on.

AND to turn off then look for

> -setwebproxystate networkservice on | off

You can also use locations to quickly switch between network configurations - these are much easier to setup in the GUI.  System Preferences -> Network  (Edit Locations on the Locations dropdown).  However, once setup, network setup has an easy way of switching (assuming you had a location named *viaProxy* or _to revert *standard* -

```sh
networksetup -switchtolocation viaProxy
networksetup -switchtolocation standard
```

Comment: Good point @user3439894 - will add to it when I have a free moment.

Answer (score -1):

First check which adapter is available:

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

View the proxy status:

```
networksetup -getwebproxy "Wi-Fi"
```

Set a proxy:

```
networksetup -setwebproxy "Wi-fi" 127.0.0.1 8080
```

Turn off a proxy:

```
networksetup -setwebproxystate "Wi-fi" off
```

Comment: You may want to consider the global audience here :-)